# Vim's <Plug> based mappings don't work with :normal command

Tags: vim

Say, I have the following

```
:nm <Plug>Ls :ls<CR>
:nm <Leader>L <Plug>Ls
```

When I do a <kbd>,L</kbd> (`,` being the leader), I do get the output of `:ls` command. I also get the output when I do `:normal ,L`, but I don't when doing the following

```
:normal <Leader>L
:normal <Plug>Ls
```

I can understand why the first isn't working, I suppose I have to do something like `execute 'normal ' . mapleader . 'L'`. What I can't figure out is the second one. It doesn't give me any error, It just doesn't do anything, which is what driving me crazy. I couldn't find anything on this in the docs either.

What I want to do is run whatever is mapped to `<Plug>Ls`, from the command mode (in a function actually). Any dark hacks needed for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They do work with normal, you just are not supplying it `<Plug>`, you supply `<`, `P`, `l`, `u`, `g`, `>`. Correct syntax is

```
:execute "normal \<Plug>Ls"
```

Same applies to `feedkeys()`: `call feedkeys("\<Plug>Ls")`, not `call feedkeys("<Plug>Ls")`.

Also note that `execute "normal ".mapleader."L"` should not really be ever used as if `mapleader` changes after you execute `:nm <Leader>L <Plug>Ls`, then this `:execute …` will try to call nonexistent mapping (`mapleader` changes do not affect already created mappings). And you there are no ways to know whether `mapleader` has changed.

Comment: Yep, that works. Actually, I did try this, but with single quotes. I feel so stupid right now! Thanks for this wonderful answer. Never knew there's a difference in quotes' usage.